# what is query for Incremental Backup

Tags: c#, sql-server

I made one Console Application by which I took `Full` as well as `Differential Backups`;
Below is Function, Now  I am searching For query by which I can do same for `Incremental Backup`.

**FullBackup:**

```
  Success_backup = Execute_Query_Master_Database("BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = '" + Backup_FileName + "' ");
  Success_Alter_DB = Execute_Query_Master_Database("ALTER DATABASE " + DatabaseName + "  SET MULTI_USER ");
```

**Differential BAckup:**

```
 Success_backup = Execute_Query_Master_Database("BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = '" + Backup_FileName + "' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL  ");
 Success_Alter_DB = Execute_Query_Master_Database("ALTER DATABASE " + DatabaseName + "  SET MULTI_USER ");


    public static  bool Execute_Query_Master_Database(string strQuery)
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = null;
        SqlCommand _command;

        {
            string connectionstring = @"Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog='master';User Id='" + UserName + "';Password='" + PassWord + "'";
            Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            Conn.Open();
            _command = new SqlCommand();
            _command.Connection = Conn;
            _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            _command.CommandText = strQuery;
            _command.CommandTimeout = 0;

            _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {              
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured in Function - Execute_Scaler_Master_Database()");
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message as below : ");
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine();

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            _command = null;
            Conn.Close();           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190412%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is the MSDN post describing the backup options of the SQL Server. I don't see the option of an incremental backup, at least with native SQL commands.

I would suggest considering using [Transaction Log Backups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191429.aspx) which actually would cover you in every possible scenario.

Hope I helped!